# i'm trying to create a route that returns the sum of all the values of a params in a collection

Tags: javascript, database, backend, strapi

i really don't know what I'm doing wrong... it returns an array with the number of rows in the collection but all null.
i followed the documentation perfectly but i'm just extremely confused

basically i have a collection in my database called mytest, and i'm trying to add the valuses in each document (token) to return when i call the route /mytest-sum

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Retrieve records.
   *
   * @return {Array}
   */

  async Sum(ctx) {
    let entities;
    if (ctx.query._q) {
      entities = await strapi.services.mytest.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      entities = await strapi.services.mytest.find(ctx.query);
    }

    //return entities.map(entity => sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.mytest}));

    entities = entities.map(entity => (entity, { model: strapi.models.mytest }));

    entities = entities.map(entry => {
      entry = Object.assign(entry, {
        sumField: entry.token
      });
    });
   return entities;

  
  },
};``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
async Add(ctx) {
  let add = 0;
  let fruits = []

  // get data from database
let entities;
    if (ctx.query._q) {
      entities = await strapi.services.mytest.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      entities = await strapi.services.mytest.find(ctx.query);
    }


    //get specific data-field from data  and map it to an array
    fruits = entities.map(entity => sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.mytest }).token);

    // add array values in for loop
    for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
      add += fruits[i];
    }
//return sum as a number 
return add;
}};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).